# GitLab Package Registry - stable or devel channel?

Tags: gitlab, registry, kubernetes-helm

When pushing packages to GitLab package registry, you have the option to push to the stable or devel channel. In the UI, it does not specify which channel the package exists in. How can you tell if a package exists in the stable or devel channel?